# Writing HTML in email Newbie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there any sample application/tutorial that demonstrates how to write `HTML` code using `[mailComposer setMessageBody:nil isHTML:_________];`

I simply want to write some `HTML` code here, how do i code it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write your HTML code as `NSString` and set it to the composer body. Then set `isHTML` to `YES`:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSString *emailBody = @"<p><b>Hello World</b></p>";                         
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

[RTFM](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) ;)

Comment: and, is there a way to make the `TextView` where the text for the body of the email is printed uneditable ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786999/disable-editing-on-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/4787904#4787904)

Comment: Also note that it Apple forbids that, so your app will be rejected if you do that