# MFMailComposeViewController - Readonly view

Tags: xcode, security, email

I understand that Apple doesn't want potential spams from applications.

I understand the need of asking the user weither he actually wants to send the email.

But couldn't we at least prevent him to change the content ?

I need this because my application would give users the ability to send logs and eventually db file to a support service, like many desktop applications send crash reports with a single confirmation.

I know that I can use webservices to ask a server to send an email for me, but since my application is an internal company one, the security involved is restrictive enough not to allow it.

**So the question is:**

Is there a way to send an email from an iOS application without allowing the user to alter the recipients, title or content ?

---

Update: I need the user to see that he have only the choice to confirm or cancel the mail.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786999/disable-editing-on-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: Thank you, but it is a workarround that only prevents the user to change the content letting him think that he could still make it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add a UIView with a lightText UIColor over part of the view. I made it so that I could only press cancel or send.

I didn't add any auto resizing mask to it because my app is portrait only. So if you need to support landscape orientation you need to add that as well.

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *blanket = [[UIView alloc] init];
    CGRect blanketFrame = mailController.view.frame;
    blanketFrame.size.height -= 40;
    blanketFrame.origin.y += 40;
    blanket.frame = blanketFrame;
    blanket.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
    [mailController.view addSubview:blanket];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Scott

Answer (score 0):

If you need the user to have only the choice to cancel or send, it seems that the answer is NOPE